# sum of all the digits of the integers from one integer to another

Tags: number-theory

Given integers a and b, calculate the sum of all the digits that appear in numbers in the range [a, b]

b can be of the range 10^6

I need the formula badly

Comment: Ouch, you really mean the digits in all the integer numbers from the interval? Any relaxation, like $a, b \ge 0$?

Comment: yes a,b>=0 that's confirmed

Comment: Does your digit sum involve repetition? E.g. what is the digit sum of $99$ for you? $18$ or $9$?

Comment: its 18....no repetition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's calculate the sum of all the digits of the numbers from 1 to $a$, and we will note it $f(a)$.

Write $a = a_0 + a_1 10^1 + ... + a_n 10^n$ where $0\le a_i \le 9$ is an integer for all $i\in[1,n]$. We have more specifically :

$$a_k = \left\lfloor{a-\left\lfloor {a\over10^{k+1}}\right\rfloor10^{k+1}\over10^k}\right\rfloor$$

Assume $a\ge0$. (as an example, we will use $a=1578$).

Now compute the sum of the digits of one certain power :

---

- Units : We have all the unit digits from 1 to $1570$ which give 
  $$157 \times (1+2+...+9) = 157\times 45 = 45\left\lfloor {a\over10}\right\rfloor $$

And all the unit digits from $1570$ to $1578$, which are (easily enough) :
$$1+2+...+8= \sum_{k=1}^{a_0}k$$

---

- Tens : We similiraly have the tens from 1 to 1500 which gives us

$$15\times10\times(1+2+...+9) = 45\times10^{1}\left\lfloor{a\over 10^2}\right\rfloor$$

Then the ones from 1500 to 1569 which are

$$10\times(1+2+...+6) = 10^1\sum_{k=1}^{a_1-1}k$$

and finally the ones from 1570 to 1578

$$7\times(8+1) = a_1\times\left(a-10^1\left\lfloor{a\over10^1}\right\rfloor+1\right)$$

---

- $k$-th power of ten :

We similiraly get $$45 \times 10^k \left\lfloor{a\over10^{k+1}}\right\rfloor
+ 10^k\sum_{k=1}^{a_k-1}k+a_k\left(a-10^k\left\lfloor{a\over10^k}\right\rfloor+1\right)$$

Note that this formula also holds for $k=0$. Thus :

$$f(a) = \sum_{k=0}^{\left\lceil\log_{10}{a}\right\rceil}\left(45 \times 10^k \left\lfloor{a\over10^{k+1}}\right\rfloor
+ 10^k{a_k(a_k-1)\over2}+a_k\left(a-10^k\left\lfloor{a\over10^k}\right\rfloor+1\right)\right)$$

and if you don't want to compute the $a_k$s :

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lceil\log_{10}{a}\right\rceil}\left(45 \times 10^k \left\lfloor{a\over10^{k+1}}\right\rfloor
+ 10^k{\left\lfloor{a-\left\lfloor {a\over10^{k+1}}\right\rfloor10^{k+1}\over10^k}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor{a-\left\lfloor {a\over10^{k+1}}\right\rfloor10^{k+1}\over10^k}\right\rfloor-1\right)\over2}+\left\lfloor{a-\left\lfloor {a\over10^{k+1}}\right\rfloor10^{k+1}\over10^k}\right\rfloor\left(a-10^k\left\lfloor{a\over10^k}\right\rfloor+1\right)\right)$$

Note that $\left\lceil\log_{10}{a}\right\rceil$ can here be replaced by $+\infty$ since all terms become $0$ for sufficiently large values of $k$.

---

Now the sum of the digits of the numbers between $a$ to $b$ are :

- if $0\le a\le b$ : $f(b)-f(a-1)$
- if $0\le b\le a$ : $f(a)-f(b-1)$
- if $a\le 0\le b$ : $f(b)+f(-a)$
- if $b\le 0\le a$ : $f(-b)+f(a)$
- if $a\le b\le 0$ : $f(-a)-f(-b-1)$
- if $b\le a\le 0$ : $f(-b)-f(-a-1)$

Comment: It is a little easier to define $f(n)$ as the sum of all the digits from $1$ to $n$, then use $f(b)-f(a-1)$ to answer the problem.  The approach is the same, but now you know what the lower limit is.

Comment: would not the second condition be a0>=b0?

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you !

Comment: One thing @Astyx, I got the formulation of the sum of units digits of all the integers from a to b i,e, s0, but I cannot figure out the part of S1, I mean shall I replace the parts a0 and b0 with a1 and b1 while calculating S1?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: let's take a=51 and b=56, according to your formula s0 is correct but when I calculate s1, where a1=b1(in this case=5), the formula yields s1=32.5 ,but it should be 30.... its the part haunting me...

Comment: @IndranilGhosh Yes indeed, calculating $s_1$ is not as easy as I thought it would be, I'll give this more thinking, edit my answer and notify you when I do (unless you don't want me to ?)

Comment: Indeed I want you to @Astyx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47742/discussion-between-indranil-ghosh-and-astyx).

Comment: @IndranilGhosh I edited

Comment: Now It works @ Astyx..